# How do I get absolute positioning with Fancybox version 2?

Tags: fancybox, fancybox-2

We're loading a fancybox manually by passing content like so:

```
$.fancybox({
    content: content,
    showCloseButton: false,
    transitionIn: 'fade',
    transitionOut: 'fade',
    speedIn: 600,
    padding: 0,
    fixed: false
});
```

We want the fancybox to stay where it is in relation to the document after it first loads (absolute positioning).

Setting fixed to false makes the fancybox elastically stay in the center of the screen during scrolling.  We'd really like the fancybox to:

- center itself in the viewport on load
- maintain absolute positioning and stay where it is relative to the document when scrolling

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, you need to also set autoCenter to false like so:

```
$.fancybox({
    content: content,
    showCloseButton: false,
    transitionIn: 'fade',
    transitionOut: 'fade',
    speedIn: 600,
    padding: 0,
    fixed: false,
    autoCenter: false
});
```

Comment: you are using fancybox v2.x with options for v1.3.x, which are not compatible with each other, for instance `transitionIn` and `transitionOut` options don't exist in v2.x but v1.3.2+. Check the documentation for the right options of the version you are using

Comment: That's exactly what happened.  Thanks.